# Support for UDP-Lite

Tags: ip, wifi

In order to be effective, UDP-Lite requires the link layer to disable its frame CRC check for frames carrying UDP-Lite packets.  Are there any deployed link layers (Wifi?) that implement this explicit support for UDP-Lite?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Link layer checksums are by design separate for each link on the path. Any application using UDP Lite would have to assume that some hops along the path have link layer checksums and some do not. Also packet loss can happen for other reasons than corruption, so using UDP Lite doesn't mean you will get no packet loss.

Comment: I'm trying to measure whether it's worthwile to consider adding support for UDP-Lite (with application-layer FEC) to our application in order to reduce latency.